# How implement logic for increment by 100 on random bids in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I am testing Max Bid functionality via Cypress but I need to randomly bid the amount in a way that it will be incremented by 100.

`var minval = 100;  var maxval = 1000000;  var bidAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxval) + minval`

The logic is given above is for any random amount.
When I implement this logic I get this error: "Bids should be incremented by 100, input was 589"
Please share your ideas. Thank you!

Comment: _"Bids should be incremented by 100"_ Doesn't that mean `+= 100`? Is this a failed test case or a wrong input? _"Please share your ideas."_ My idea is you post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes I need numbers like: 100,700,900....

Comment: That's the reason good coding requires a basic understanding of math: `var bidAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxval / 100) * 100 + minval`

Comment: and this is failing result of test case. System requires random amounts of houndres. not with cents or any amounts like 511,  589 etc.

Comment: Why is `minval` set to `1` if the smallest possible value is `100`? It should be: `var minval = 100;  var maxval = 1000000; var bidAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxval / 100) * 100 + minval;`

Comment: You delete by 100 and then multiply by 100? Does this do anything?

Comment: No, I divide by 100, then round down, then multiply by 100, e.g.: 1234 / 100 = 12.34, floor(12.34) = 12, 12 * 100 = 1200. You need these two steps because floor(1234) = 1234

Answer (score 1):

#### Several errors to fix

The most important is that you have done nothing to ensure the bid amounts are multiples of 100. A simple way to do this is to divide by 100, round to the nearest integer, and then multiply by 100.

Second, it would be good to set minval to a real minimum acceptable value, namely 100.

Third, if you really want the values to go between minval and maxval, you should multiply the `Math.random()` by (maxval-minval) so that when you add minval, it will be in the range you want.

```js
const minval = 100;
const maxval = 1000000;
const rawBidAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxval-minval)) + minval
const roundedBidAmount = 100*Math.round(rawBidAmount/100)

console.log(roundedBidAmount)
```

Comment: @Luna, Remember to mark as correct, if it solves your question. 8-)